# What are your crowdsource translation management system recommendations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localization, yaml, crowdsourcing

I'm looking for a tool to help with crowdsourcing the translations for a web site.

Some generous translators have volunteered to help so I want to provide them with a tool to use that will make their job as easy as possible. Ideally the tool/app will be free or have only a small charge.

Ideally I'd like a translation system that makes it easy to export to YAML format or any other format (the web site is built on Ruby on Rails).

If you answer please state whether you've had experience of the tool you're suggesting or not.

Thanks in advance, Eliot

Answer (score 4):

So far this is what I've found:

http://99translations.com, http://getlocalization.com, and Facebook Translations, which allows you to use Facebook's community to translate your web site.

I'm going with Facebook Translations as this is the most appropriate for my situation. I'm attempting to write a Rails plugin to simplify using it, if I get it done I'll try to remember to update this page with a link to it.

Comment: Did you succeed in building a facebook translations rails plugin?

Comment: Sorry sliver, the plugin project is abandoned

Comment: The FaceBook Translations app is more to do with translating FB into multiple languages. Is using volunteers on github/professional transcribers working out for you? https://github.com/jensimmons/webahead-transcripts.